Help with strange Magento behaviour on VPS. Cart not updating until after page refresh, cache refreshes after navigating away from page
We're having a strange problem that we can't seem to get to the bottom of. No errors are being shown.
Within the CMS, if we click flush cache, the page quickly refreshes and nothing seems to happen. If we then navigate to another page within the CMS it takes a couple of seconds longer to load and the "The Magento cache storage has been flushed." message is displayed.
On frontend nothing happens when either updating quantity in cart or trying to remove from cart until after a page refresh.
It's like there's some sort of security measure or caching that's causing it. We've contacted our host who are saying they can't see anything. We merged the site exactly as is to another host on a cheap shared cpanel plan with the same PHP version, settings etc and it worked perfectly. We are on a VPS with a company that we have a few other services with so ideally we can fix without having to change hosts.
We're using Magento 2.4.6-p7.
Has anyone had anything similar or have any ideas as to where to look?

Update: We solved our problem. We found that litespeed cache was enabled on our server causing some strange behaviour. Adding the below to .htaccess to disable cache fixed our problems.
CacheDisable public /
CacheDisable private /

May want to register and merge with the account you posted with.
